# Create provisioning profile without physical device (archiving for TestFlight testing)

Tags: ios, iphone, testflight, provisioning-profile

I am trying to create provisioning profile by clicking `"Fix Issue"` in `Target -> General -> Identity` settings. It shows me popup `"No Devices Registered"`, so it seems like I need to have a device to create a provisioning profile. Is there any workaround? I just need to archive my app and upload it to `iTunes` for `TestFlight` testing, so the devices might come from other testers ultimately (internal or external ones), but I currently do not have an iPhone with me.

Comment: Are you able to create a provisioning profile through the Developer Portal website? I've always found the Xcode management of the profiles to be completely useless.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To Register device and use it with iTunes and TestFlight you have to create apple [developer account](http://developer.apple.com). After creating account just follow this [tutorial](https://www.genuitec.com/products/myeclipse/learning-center/mobile/ios-application-provisioning-requirements/) to setup certificate and provisioning profile, which are requires to accomplish your task.

Comment: I have registered developer account but there is no device as is specified in the question. Do I really need to go through the tutorial? It seems that Xcode allows it to be done easier just by clicking "fix issues" in the settings, or is the tutorial specifically works for the case when we do not have device?

Comment: Just follow tutorial throughly to register your device or your client's device with developer account.

Comment: OK, I followed the tutorial, generated the certificates and downloaded the provisioning profile. Then, could you tell what to do next? I am not sure how should I integrate this info into my archive.

Comment: OK, I figured it out. Thank you!

Comment: @NikitaVlasenko - What is that you figured out.? can you share.?

Comment: the link to tutorial is not valid anymore

Answer (score 8):

First understand the meaning of provisioning profile. It says
A **provisioning profile** is a collection of **digital entities** that uniquely ties developers and devices to an authorized iPhone Development Team and enables a device to be used for testing. 
Ok this is an old definition before xcode 7 and ios 9. 
So what if you click on generic ios device and then archive. Does it throw error then? Because in my experience I can make archive of the app without any device, please select generic device rather than specific one for archiving.
As for credentials, you must create two certificates:
One for development, which allows you to run your Xcode projects on your plugged-in devices.
One for distribution, which allows you to export ad hoc builds and submit apps to the store using your certified Mac.

**The bottom line is**: Since you’ll be building apps for distribution, you’ll also need a paid developer account.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you're code signing the application with a Distribution provisioning profile, and have your Distribution certificate installed in your keychain.

It sounds like you're accidentally code signing with a standard Development profile/certificate, which is why your app will only run on that profile's listed devices.

And you need to send invites on their email address to test the app.

Answer (score 1):

> You can't.
>
> Using your paid account to distribute apps requires having at least one device connected to Xcode, on your mac, and registered in the Member Center.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/99907