# Is it possible to build Flutter iOS release app and push to Firebase App Distribution without iOS device?

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

Developing an Android/iOS app with Flutter, i'm trying to let my iOS users donwload my app by uploading it on Firebase App Distribution.

But when i try to build release iOS app, it asks a provisioning profiles. I've done a App ID, the certificated developer, but it seems to need a device ID too. I don't have an iOS device but i only want a release .ipa.

I understand that i have to sign the app, but i don't have or want to run it now on a iOS device as I just want to upload it on Firebase App Distribution. I test my app on a iPhone simulator and it works very well.

Is there a solution to just build and push the app ?

(I also tried the tricks by zipping it and change extension... and it doesn't work too)

edit:
[Create provisioning profile without physical device (archiving for TestFlight testing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34564172/create-provisioning-profile-without-physical-device-archiving-for-testflight-te)
I found someone else who had quite the same issue, but 4 years ago, hope somethings changed

Comment: If the answer helped you please upvote it and mark it as correct thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible, when creating a provisioning profile you need to select which devices to include in the provisioning profile. Therefore you need to get the udid of each device so they can open the application in that device.